# How to make this pyspark program faster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

df_nyc has 178 rows and df has 14 million rows. 
**dy_nyc schema** ['Zip Code':int,'lat':int,'lon':int]
**df schema** ['lat':int,'lon':int] 
I'm trying to map zipcodes in df_nyc to (lat,lon) in df.
Task I'm trying to achieve here is:

1. For every (latitude, longitude) in **df_nyc** calculate the **distance** between (latitude, longitude) in **df**.  Let this distance be d
2. For each (latitude, longitude) in df find **minimum** distance (d).
3. Find the zip code for every (latitude, longitude) in df based on (latitude,longitude) in df_nyc corresponding to minimum d.

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,DoubleType,IntegerType
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .getOrCreate()

    nyc_zip_sp = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("s3://bucket1/zips.csv") #178 rows
    #nyc_zip_sp.show()
    df_nyc=nyc_zip_sp.select(nyc_zip_sp['ZIP Codes'].cast("int"), 
                             nyc_zip_sp['lat'].cast("float"),        
                             nyc_zip_sp['long'].cast("float"))
    df_nyc = df_nyc.withColumnRenamed("ZIP Codes", "zip")

    df= spark.read.option("header",True).csv(f's3://nyc-tlc/trip data/yellow_tripdata_2009-01.csv') # 14 Million rows

    df1=df.select(df['Start_Lat'].cast('float'),df['Start_Lon'].cast('float'))
    df1.createTempView("df1")
    df_nyc.createTempView("df2")

    #Perform cross join on df1, df2 & find distance b/w (lat,lon) of df1,df2. Named as min_dist
    df2 =spark.sql("""SELECT  df1.Start_Lat as lat, df1.Start_Lon as lon, df2.zip, df2.lat as mlat, df2.long as mlon, (2 * 6371 * asin(sqrt(sin(df2.lat-df1.Start_Lat/2)*sin(df2.lat-df1.Start_Lat/2)+cos(df1.Start_Lat)*cos(df2.lat)*sin(df2.long-df1.Start_Lon/2)*sin(df2.long-df1.Start_Lon/2)))) as min_dist
                    from df1
                    cross join df2

                  """)

    df2.createTempView("zipcode_table")

    # Window func over (lat,lon) and find min(min_dist)   
    df3=spark.sql("""SELECT DISTINCT z.lat, z.lon, zip
                     FROM
                         (SELECT  lat, lon, MIN(min_dist) OVER(PARTITION BY lat,lon) AS dist
                          FROM zipcode_table) AS d 
                     JOIN zipcode_table AS Z 
                     ON z.lat = d.lat AND z.lon = d.lon AND min_dist = dist

                  """)

    df3.createTempView("zipcode_table_1")

    zip_count=spark.sql("""
                SELECT zip,count(*) as total_count
                FROM zipcode_table_1
                GROUP BY zip

              """)

    zip_count.write.mode('overwrite').option("header",True).csv('s3://nyc-analysis/zip_2009')
   ```

Comment: Where is the bottleneck when you look at stages and tasks? You are exploding the data to the size of 2.5B rows. Is your cluster big enough to hold that in memory? Otherwise it will spill to disk and performance is degraded. Maybe an approach would be to just append the nyc dataset to each row and then write a udf to do these checks. Sklean should have the knn algorithm which is quite efficient, and this would way you just parallelize the 14M rows. Other approaches could include approximate distance calculations via eg annoy.

Comment: One way to resolve your issue is by appending the data instead of taking everything at once so that there is no bottleneck.